# Ajax timeout on Samsung TV

Tags: ajax, samsung-smart-tv

I've set up a longpolling ajax call from a Samsung TV App (HTML). It seems to timeout after some minutes waiting. It does not time out running in a normal web browser.

Is there a timeout set by the Samsung TV to exit AJAX/HTTP request? If so, how to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a watchdog timer in the Samsung TV.  Sometimes you need to disable it if you app will be waiting too long for a response.

The call to disable the watchdog is in the Samsung forums.  Just remember to re-enable it afterwards.